# os.pipe() forcing me to write an input

Tags: python, c, linux, file-descriptor

I have code in python which I modify the stdin and stderr, it work succesfuly but at the end of the program it asks for input (for the shell)
python code:

```py
import os
import subprocess

stdin_read, stdin_write = os.pipe()
stderr_read, stderr_write = os.pipe()

os.write(stdin_write, b'\x00\x0a\x00\xff')
os.write(stderr_write, b'\x00\x0a\x02\xff')

subprocess.Popen(["./prog"],stdin=stdin_read, stderr=stderr_read)
```

code in c (prog.c)

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char buf[4];
    read(0, buf, 4);
    if(!memcmp(buf, "\x00\x0a\x00\xff", 4)){
        printf("success -A \n");
    }

    read(2, buf, 4);
    if(!memcmp(buf, "\x00\x0a\x02\xff", 4)){
        printf("success -B \n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I typed the`echo "hello world"`

[terminal-prove](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kn0va.png)

I was expecting the program to end and not let me write input to the shell.
Do I need to close the pipe I created? What should I do so that this won`t happen to me?

Comment: what does "not let me write input to the shell" mean?

Comment: every file descriptor (including pipes) that a process opens is automatically closed when the process goes away. If all the descriptors are closed the file (or pipe) is closed

Comment: As you can see in the picture, after "Success A! Sucesss B!" I could type "echo "hello world"". and I dont understand why I could do that, according to the program there is no input to the shell

Answer (score 1):

Notice the Python program ended **before** printing `success -A` and `success -B`. Apparently `./prog` started, then Python ended, then `./prog` printed its thing. The pipe still exists until all programs that have access to it close it (or end) so `./prog` can still read the data from both pipes.

You typed the `echo` command into the shell prompt after `python` ended. It's still the same prompt even though `./prog` printed two lines in the middle, between the prompt and your command.

If you want Python to wait for `./prog` to finish you can do that:

```
my_proc = subprocess.Popen(["./prog"],stdin=stdin_read, stderr=stderr_read)
my_proc.wait()
```